# Can I run a http server in nativescript?

Tags: nativescript

Is it possible to run an in-app HTTP server with NativeScript either as a background service or as part of the foreground app itself ? I am looking to utilize a common code base across a system of applications which would communicate to a local server which handles some parts of the application's communication to my servers. Where, I intend to create a HTTP server in the app which can just serve as a REST server for the app. Is it possible ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its possible since nativescript doesn't offer any module or plugin that supports the creation of http servers. First option is to look for a nativescript module in npm that supports http server creation, Second option is to create an http server using the native API's with javascript, Third and last option (which I prefer) is to make your own server using nodejs or any server side script and run that server on a certain machine then from your nativescript app you can access that server using the fetch module or the http module :)